# Moodle and email question: Emails displaying special characters as & amp ; and not &

Tags: html, email, encoding, moodle

I have a custom module installed in Moodle (the certificate module). You can have the certificate emailed to the student. Currently, I have an ampersand in my course name and it's showing up as & amp ;. Here's what I mean: 
[image]

The ampersand is showing in the email subject line and not getting encoded.

It is happening on gmail, and Mac mail. Any ideas on how to fix this or is this something that is out of my control?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't post your HTML code, so it's difficult to see what might be happening.

An ampersand `&` next to another character might be interpreted as by the email client displaying the email as ASCII code, since the ampersand is used to display extended characters like the copyright symbol: © which can be displayed as: `&#169;` or `&copy;`.

Extended characters are the characters that were not included in the standard ASCII character set. The original ASCII character set included all of the lowercase and uppercase letters on the keyboard (`a`, `A`), which are represented with ASCII codes 0 to 127. Anything above 127 is an extended character, for instance the Euro symbol, "€" `&#128;` `&euro;` or the trade mark symbol "™" `&#153;` `&trade;`.

- https://ascii-code.com

One thought is that your email is not being encoded in UTF-8, which allows you to use extended characters without much difficulty. Do you have something like this in the email head: `<meta charset="utf-8">`.

Good luck.

Comment: Since it's Moodle, I'm not sure where I would find the document head to set the character set. It's probably in the layout files if I had to guess. But the meta charset might be the issue. I'll check the theme files and see. Thanks.

Comment: @Nick0989 I do not use Moodle, but if you can send yourself an email, you can click the "view on web" and look in the header to see what is there. If you cannot make changes, using ASCII characters will always yield the best results. Use a site like https://ascii-code.com to figure out the correct code for extended characters.